# Getting 403 forbidden while upload image to aws s3 with retrofit 2

Tags: android, amazon-s3, retrofit2, okhttp

Am getting 403 forbidden error while uploading image to amazon aws s3 with pre-signed url.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide more info (like code samples) so we can better help you. Also, please take the time to read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Can you give a sample of the URI (changing the sensitive portions)? Does upload using CURL work? Can you paste the 403-forbidden response including headers? (again changing sensitive portions)